# take the year from date type in a pandas dataframe column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, multidimensional-array, dataframe

I have year data in a pandas dataframe as following:

```
0     06/09/1937 
1     22/11/1972
```

and i would like to extract only the year data:

```
0     1937 
1     1972
```

My code:

```
features["year"] = df["birth_date"].str.split('/',2)
features["year"] = features["year"][:2]
```

I got an error as:

> ValueError: Can only tuple-index with a MultiIndex

Then I tried

```
features["year"] = [x[2] for x in features["year"]]
```

> TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable

I use Python 3.
Could you tell me the reasons for these two errors and how to correct them?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Convert the dtype to `datetime` using `pd.to_datetime` then you can just use the linked answer, as simple as that

Comment: Hi, The linked answer works fine for me. By the way, can you explan me in some words how these two errors in my question produced?@EdChum

Comment: this `features["year"][:2]` is invalid syntax, it thinks you're trying to index a multi-index which is why it raised the error, the other issue is probably because you have missing value `NaN` so you can't subscript this

Comment: Thank you EdChum, can you give me an example of tuple index and multi index please @EdChum?

Comment: Please read the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html) SO is not a user forum

Answer (score 0):

You need:

```
features["year"] = df["birth_date"].str.split('/',2)
features["year"] = features["year"].str[:2]
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast response. However, I get NaN in the year data with your solution.

Comment: no problem, try duplicate solution, if not working, let me know.